# Flutter: Showing a Future List of MaterialButtons

Tags: button, flutter, future

I am writing a flutter App.
My current problem is that I want to show a list of buttons to open different pdf files from a website. The buttonlist is created using webscraping. The function returns a Future List of Strings. From this List of Strings a Future List of Material Buttons is created.

Because the webscraping needs a long time, a LoadingDialog should be shown while the buttonlist is not ready. Afterwards, the buttonlist should be shown.

With my current code, the buttonlist is created twice. First time it is created and a LoadingDialog is shown. Then the LoadingDialog is hided, the screen is white, the buttonlist is created again and when it is ready, it is shown on the screen.

How can i prevent the list from re-forming?

This is my code:

```
class PlanScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AdvancedAppBar(context: context),
      body: PlanForm(),
    );
  }
}


class PlanForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  PlanState createState() {
    return PlanState();
  }
}

class PlanState extends State<PlanForm> {
  String pathPDF;
  List<MaterialButton> _buttonsList = [];
  bool _listVariable = false;


Future<List<String>> doed()async {
// doed returns a Future<List<String>> with file names
}

  @override
  void initState() {
  createFileOfPdfUrl("File-URL").then((f){setState((){pathPDF = f.path;});});
  super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Widget>> _buildButtonsWithNames() async{
    List<String> list = [];
    await doed().then((value){list = value;});
    int length = list.length;
    print("Länge der List " + length.toString());
    _buttonsList = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      List<String> linkSplitted = list[0].split("/");
      String buttonName = linkSplitted[linkSplitted.length-1];
      _buttonsList
          .add(new MaterialButton(
              height: 40.0,
              minWidth: 300.0,
              color: phwtblue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              child: new Text(buttonName,  textScaleFactor: 2.0,),
              onPressed: () {
                bool hi = true;
                if(buttonName.contains(".html"))
                {
                Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new MyApp2()),
                );
                } else if (buttonName.contains(".pdf"))
                {
                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new PDFView(pathPDF)),
                  );
                }

                }
                ));
                print(list.length);
                list.removeAt(0);
              }
              print(_buttonsList.length);
    return _buttonsList;
  }

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Widget>>(
          future: _buildButtonsWithNames().then((list){_buttonsList = list;}),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Widget>> snapshot) {
            while(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
              showLoadingDialog();
              return Column();
             }
            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
               hideLoadingDialog();
               _listVariable = false;
               return LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
      return SingleChildScrollView( 
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: _buttonsList,
          )
        )
        )
        );
        }
    );
          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason** 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11426#issuecomment-414047398 
didUpdateWidget of the FutureBuilder state is being called every time a rebuild is issued. This function checks if the old future object is different from the new one, and if so, refires the FutureBuilder. To get past this, we can call the Future somewhere other than in the build function.

**Solution** 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11426#issuecomment-414047398

code snippet

```
Future<List<Widget>> Function() _future;
...
@override
void initState() {
  //createFileOfPdfUrl("File-URL").then((f){setState((){pathPDF = f.path;});});
  super.initState();
  _future = _buildButtonsWithNames;
}
...
FutureBuilder<List<Widget>>(
        future: _future().then((list) {
          _buttonsList = list;
        }),
```

full test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: PlanScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlanScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("test"),
      ),
      body: PlanForm(),
    );
  }
}

class PlanForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  PlanState createState() {
    return PlanState();
  }
}

class PlanState extends State<PlanForm> {
  String pathPDF;
  List<MaterialButton> _buttonsList = [];
  bool _listVariable = false;

  Future<List<String>> doed() async {
// doed returns a Future<List<String>> with file names
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {});
    return ["123", "456", "abc", "def"];
    /*setState(() {
      return ["123", "456", "abc", "def"];
    });*/
  }

  Future<List<Widget>> Function() _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //createFileOfPdfUrl("File-URL").then((f){setState((){pathPDF = f.path;});});
    super.initState();
    _future = _buildButtonsWithNames;
  }

  Future<List<Widget>> _buildButtonsWithNames() async {
    print("_buildButtonsWithNames()");
    List<String> list = [];
    await doed().then((value) {
      list = value;
    });
    int length = list.length;
    print("Länge der List " + length.toString());
    _buttonsList = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      List<String> linkSplitted = list[0].split("/");
      String buttonName = linkSplitted[linkSplitted.length - 1];
      _buttonsList.add(new MaterialButton(
          height: 40.0,
          minWidth: 300.0,
          color: Colors.blue,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text(
            buttonName,
            textScaleFactor: 2.0,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            bool hi = true;
            if (buttonName.contains(".html")) {
              //Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new MyApp2()),
              //);
            } else if (buttonName.contains(".pdf")) {
              //Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new PDFView(pathPDF)),
              //);
            }
          }));
      print(list.length);
      list.removeAt(0);
    }
    print(_buttonsList.length);
    return _buttonsList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build");
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Widget>>(
            future: _future().then((list) {
              _buttonsList = list;
            }),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Widget>> snapshot) {
              while (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                //showLoadingDialog();
                print("show loading");
                return Column();
              }
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                //hideLoadingDialog();
                print("hide loading");
                _listVariable = false;
                return LayoutBuilder(builder:
                    (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: ConstrainedBox(
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(
                            minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                              child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: _buttonsList,
                          ))));
                });
              }
            }));
  }
}
```